# How to create a mixin for js/modal/confirm.js

Tags: jquery, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, magento-ui

I want to create a mixin for `js/modal/confirm.js` but that widget returns some javascript to make it possible to create an instance of the widget instead of the widget itself.

So it returns this

```
// vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js
...
    return function (config) {
        return $('<div></div>').html(config.content).confirm(config);
    };
});
```

instead of

```
// vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js
...
    return $.mage.confirm;
});
```